# How to resize image size in Ionic/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, canvas, base64

I am new to Ionic. I reduce image size using canvas for the iPad app, but the base64 string is created as a black image. 
Please suggest me my mistake.

```
var fileReader=new FileReader();

           fileReader.onload=function(event){
               $rootScope.$broadcast('event:file:selected',{image:event.target.result});
               Image64b = event.target.result;
               // $scope.ImageNo2 = Image64b;
               // var replaceStr = "data:image/png"
               // resultPdfbase64 = Image64a.replace("data:image/jpeg", replaceStr);
               // $scope.ImageNo2 = resultPdfbase64;
              var imgObj = new Image();
              imgObj.src = Image64b ;
              var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
              canvas.width =  225;
              canvas.height = 225;
              canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0,225,225);

              $scope.imgggg2 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
               $scope.$apply();
           }

           fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);


$scope.imggg2 used for base64 string in this $scope.imggg2 always value becomes      data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
```

Which has black image, please suggest me mistake. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you able to fetch correct base64 string?...try decoding the string to verify its correctness

Comment: Can you create a codepen that reproduces the error?